# Center jQuery popUp dialog with auto width and auto height

Tags: jquery, dialog, popup, position, center

**I have following initialization of jQuery popUp dialog, with dynamic content :**

```
  jQuery("#popUp").live("click", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("<div></div>")
        .addClass("dialog")
        .attr("id", "popUpDialog")
        .appendTo("body")
        .dialog({
            title: jQuery(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
            close: function() { jQuery(this).remove(); },
            modal: true,
            hide: { effect: "none", duration: 150 },
            show: { effect: "none", duration: 150 },
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            position: {
                my: 'center',
                at: 'center',
            of: jQuery(window)
            }
        }).load(this.href);

    jQuery(".close").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
    });
});
```

});

I am sorry for this simplest question , but I can not place the popUp window on center of the whole page . The problem is in :

```
                  position: {
                  my: 'center',
                  at: 'center',
              of: jQuery(window)}
```

Comment: position: {
                my: 'center',
                at: 'center',
            of: jQuery(window)
            } remove this it bydefault it show dialog box in center

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because the dialog is being positioned before its content is loaded, and therefore it's size is changing. Change your logic so that the content is loaded first, and then instantiate the dialog:

```
$('<div />', {
  class: 'dialog',
  id: 'popUpDialog' 
}).appendTo('body').load(this.href, function() {
  // set up the dialog in the callback of the AJAX request...
  $(this).dialog({
    title: jQuery(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
    close: function() { jQuery(this).remove(); },
    modal: true,
    hide: { effect: "none", duration: 150 },
    show: { effect: "none", duration: 150 },
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    position: {
      my: 'center',
      at: 'center',
      of: window
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: I use it a lot in my application (MVC) .On click of button that have id 'popUp' the content will be displayed in popUp ,  how i can to change my logic ,can I use SeTimeOut function?

Comment: You could, you would need to set the left position to `(window.width / 2) - (dialog.width / 2)` and the same for the top position.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough for position option :

```
position:'center'
```

does it work ?

Comment: no it doesn't work ,i t will work if I will indicate width and height , with width:auto and height:auto is doesn't work...